# In Bigquery, How to get Start Day of the week from available table list?

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery, dayofweek, week-number

**Input:**
Have got a table in bigquery, in below format

```
Store   Date        WeekNumber
11      2019-11-14  201953
11      2019-11-12  201953
11      2019-11-17  201953
11      2019-11-15  201953
11      2019-11-11  201953
11      2019-11-13  201953
11      2019-11-16  201953
11      2019-11-19  201954
11      2019-11-21  201954
11      2019-11-22  201954
```

**Scenario:** From the above sample table, have to group by week number and fetch week's start date as mentioned in sample output.

**Sample Output:**

```
Store   StartDate       WeekNumber
11      2019-11-11      201953
11      2019-11-19      201954
```

**Query Snippet:**

```
SELECT
Store,
#StartDate
WeekNumber 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY WeekNumber,Store
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT strore, 
  DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(MONDAY)) StartDate,
  EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY) FROM date) WeekNumber,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY strore, StartDate, WeekNumber
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 11 store, DATE '2019-11-14' date UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-12' UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-17' UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-15' UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-11' UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-13' UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-16' UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-19' UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-21' UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-22' 
)
SELECT store, 
  DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK(MONDAY)) StartDate,
  EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY) FROM date) WeekNumber,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY store, StartDate, WeekNumber
```

output is

```
Row store   StartDate   WeekNumber  cnt  
1   11      2019-11-11  45          7    
2   11      2019-11-18  46          3
```

> UPDATE: in initial answer I've missed requirement:  `start date [should be taken] from the available dates for that week from table`

Below query does exactly this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Store, 
  MIN(Date) StartDate,
  WeekNumber,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY Store, WeekNumber
```

if to apply to [updated] sample data from your question

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 11 Store, '2019-11-14' Date, 201953 WeekNumber UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-12', 201953 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-17', 201953 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-15', 201953 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-11', 201953 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-13', 201953 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-16', 201953 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-19', 201954 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-21', 201954 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-22', 201954 
)
```

result is

```
Row Store   StartDate   WeekNumber  cnt  
1   11      2019-11-11  201953      7    
2   11      2019-11-19  201954      3
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! But this doesn't work for the available data in table, 
1. It takes default start date for the week instead of start date from the available dates for that week from table.  
2. WeekNumber must be taken from table, here it defaults [have edited 'WeekNumber' for more understanding in question sample]

Comment: your second bullet in comments easy to address - just use WeekNumber from the table and do not calculate it - that simple!! as of first bullet - i see what you mean now - this was definitely not clear from the original question - but now when you explicitly mentioned this  - it makes sense :o) I will update my answer later in a day when have time

Comment: Simply perfect! Thanks for your help :)